# Plotting Euler spiral in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am doing a paper on famous planar curves and one of them is the Euler spiral or cornu spiral. The only representation of this curve is over the Fresnel integrals, but how do I plot the Fresnel integrals in LaTex.

Comment: Have you tried approximating those integrals by the well-known series and plot these instead? Who could tell the difference?

Comment: Why does every mathematician assume perfect math knowledge on TeX-SX ? Is it an arXiv thing?

Comment: Code to produce the Euler spiral is given in several languages at the following link.  Perhaps you could adopt it to tikz-pgf or another language of your choice.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral#Code_for_producing_an_Euler_spiral